# I want to add in scroll button to click in button 1 on keyboard

Tags: xmouse

In the xmouse button program, how do I put it so that when I click on the mouse scroll, activate the number 1 on the keyboard? I only know how to do it with f1 to f12
{f1}. I've looked and haven't found anything that can enlighten me.

edit

it's not {num1} it's the one to zero above the letters.

Answer (score 1):

directly use `1`  instead of  `{}`
see pic below:

[image: pic]

Comment: dindt work at first time now did work thanks!